# How do I add an Access Denied Handler in spring-security-javaconfig

Tags: java, spring-security, spring-java-config

I'm using the spring-security-javaconfig library for spring security. If I were using xml config files, I'd use something like this to define a custom Access Denied page:

```
<http auto-config="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/admin*" access="ROLE_ADMIN" />
    <access-denied-handler ref="accessDeniedHandler"/>
</http>
```

Here is my security configuration class so far:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfigurator extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void registerAuthentication(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
            throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER");
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("admin").password("password").roles("ADMIN");

    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeUrls().antMatchers( "/admin").hasRole("ADMIN");
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that invoking inMemoryAuthentication() multiple times is actually creating multiple InMemoryUserDetailsManager instances. If you don't want to method chain everything, you can store the call to  auth.inMemoryAuthentication() in a variable. Or you can use method chaining as outline on the examples https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-security-javaconfig/blob/master/samples-web.md#sample-web-security-spring-java-config

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I suppose this should do the trick:

```
HttpSecurity http = ...
http.exceptionHandling().accessDeniedHandler(myAccessDeniedHandler);
```