# Spring JavaConfig: error handling with WebApplicationInitializer

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, error-handling, spring-java-config

I'm trying to handle errors such as Not Found (404), Acces Denied (403), Bad Request (400) etc. in Spring MVC web app.

I use WebApplicationInitializer instead of web.xml to initialize my web app. 
It would be simple to configure http errors handling in web.xml:

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/error/404</location>
</error-page>
```

I found how to handle Acces Denied error only:
[How do I add an Access Denied Handler in spring-security-javaconfig](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18154864/how-do-i-add-an-access-denied-handler-in-spring-security-javaconfig)

But is there any clear solution to handle http errors in web application initialized by WebApplicationInitializer?

Comment: I don't know if you do exactly the same thing with Servlet 3.0 API - [SERVLET_SPEC-50](https://java.net/jira/browse/SERVLET_SPEC-50). Nevertheless with Spring MVC 3.2+ you can handle different exceptions in a very comfortable way. Check if [@ExceptionHandler](http://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc#controller-based-exception-handling) will not be useful for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no error-page equivalent in java config servlet initialization. You have to override it on application server level